# Task 'clean' not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to rebuild my android studio project.

It is giving me the error..

> FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Task 'clean' not found in root project 'RingtoneGenerator'.
> - Try:
>   Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.

Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Please add the contents of your build.gradle files to your question.